# Unable to connect to the correct Azure's subscription with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have many tenant on Azure and I use Powershell to manage them.

I'm connect with my account:

```
Login-AzureRmConnect

Account                     SubscriptionName          TenantId                             Environment
-------                     ----------------          --------                             -----------
XXX@XXXX.XXX                Microsoft Partner Network XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX            AzureCloud
```

When I want to change te subscription with SubscriptionID valid i have this answers :

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX"
Select-AzureRmSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-X ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError : (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand
```

And when I do `Get-AzureRmSubscription` :

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription
AVERTISSEMENT : Unable to acquire token for tenant 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
AVERTISSEMENT : Unable to acquire token for tenant 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
AVERTISSEMENT : Unable to acquire token for tenant 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
AVERTISSEMENT : Unable to acquire token for tenant 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
AVERTISSEMENT : Unable to acquire token for tenant 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'

Name                          Id                                   TenantId                             State
----                          --                                   --------                             -----
Microsoft Partner Network     XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX            XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX            Enabled
Microsoft Azure               XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX            XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX            Enabled
XXXX - XXXXXXX                XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX            XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX            Enabled
```

Before it worked, in Azure's Portal no change.

Can You help me ?

Thanks You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am unable to use comments.

Could it be that the other subscriptions are based in a different tenant? 
If that is the case, please try to use `Connect-AzureRmAccount -TenantId`